# Python: calculate the most and the least active customers

Tags: python, spyder

I have a question on how to find the most and the least active customers.

We were given a group of different names. For example `"sam, sam, luke, luke, luke"`

We are asked to find the most frequent name and the least frequent name using python(spyder). These results need to be *reflected* in a box in `wxFormBuilder`.

I am not sure what exactly I should do.

Here is what I have so far for looking for the most active customer:

```
def mostactive(self,parent):
    for name in range (self.m_listBox1.GetCount()):     <--- the name of the box is m_listBox1
        mostactivecustomer=str(self.m_listBox1.GetString(name))
        self.m_textCtrl2.Value(mostactivecustomer)      <---- the result box is called m_textCtrl2
```

Thank you!

Comment: We are (hopefully) not going to do your homework for you. How have you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is more a question of basic maths, mean, median, mode etc.

You could put all the names into a list and count the names in each, then write them back to the text box.