# Python writing codes to get the most active customer and least customer

Tags: python, spyder, wxformbuilder

We are asked to design a GUI to calculate the most active and least active customers.
There are two buttons at the bottom that will calculate the most and the least active customer.
There is also a results area that will display the result of pressing the two buttons.

There is a list box, and two buttons under it. Names will show in the list box. For instance, when I enter "sam" in the textCtrl number one, and click add customer button. Sam will be appear in the list box. After you enter different or same names a few times. A list with names is the list box. For instance, there are three "sam"s and two "justin"s in the list box. When I click "most active button", name sam will appear in the result box. When I click least active button, name justin will appear in the result box.

I successfully defined the add customer button, but I have no idea how to define the buttons calculating the most active and least active customers. Someone told me I need to use count function, but I am not sure how to do it.

Here is what I got so far:

```
def addcustomer(self,event):
    try:
        name=str(self.m_textCtrl1.Value)
        self.m_listBox1.Append(str(name))
    except:
        wx.MessageBox("This can't be empty.")

def mostactive(self,parent):
```

Can someone help me on the next step?
Thank you!
P.S. The name of the result box is m_textCtrl2
The name of the list box is m_listbox1

Comment: "We are asked to design a GUI" makes it sound like you want us to finish your homework for you.  Suggestion: **try** to write the `mostactive` and `leastactive` methods, then share your code if it isn't completely working, and I predict you will have more help.  I just noticed you posted the identical question 4 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127280/python-calculate-the-most-and-the-least-active-customers

Comment: def mostactive(self,parent):
        namescounter = Counter(self.m_listBox1.Append)
        try:
               names = self.m_listBox1.Append
               self.m_textCtrl2.Value = namescounter.most_common(names)
        except:
             wx.MessageBox("It doesn't work.")

Comment: I tried again.It doesn't work...:(

Answer (score 0):

collections.Counter has a really convenient method `.most_common` for getting the most common items in a list:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> namesCounter = Counter(['Rod', 'Rod', 'Rod', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Freddie'])
>>> namesCounter.most_common(1)
[('Rod', 3)]
```

The least common items could be obtained like this:

```
>>> [(k, min(namesCounter.values())) for k, v in namesCounter.iteritems() if v == min(namesCounter.values())]
[('Freddie', 1)]
```

... though that does look a bit un-pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your code like this :

```
customer = {}

def addcustomer(self,event):
    try:
        name=str(self.m_textCtrl1.Value)
        self.m_listBox1.Append(str(name))
        if name in customer:
            customer[name] += 1
        else:
            customer[name] = 1
    except:
        wx.MessageBox("This can't be empty.")
```

final customer dictionary will be = {'sam' : 3, 'justin' : 2}
,and use

`max(customer, key=customer.get)`
`min(customer, key=customer.get)`

to get the most active and least customer.